# Remove charset from Rails content type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a old-stupid service making request to my app that fails when the Content-Type include the charset line

```
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
```

and I don't know how to remove it from my rails response. Every time that I override the headers forcing just the first part (Content-Type  text/html) Rails adds the charset to the header...

Comment: I have the exact same problem and Chuba's solution doens't seem to work for me. Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Rails 3/4, the code that handles this is in `ActionDispatch::Response.assign_default_content_type_and_charset!` in [actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb).

Setting `response.headers['Content-Type']` instead of `response.content_type` should eliminate the charset.  Chubas' solution does this for all responses.

---

For Rails 2, the code that handles this is in `content_type=` and `charset=` in [actionpack/lib/action_controller/response.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/response.rb).

As Carson's solution describes, setting `ActionController::Base.default_charset = nil` should eliminate the charset.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
class MyController

  after_filter :remove_charset

  def remove_charset
    headers['Content-type'] = "text/html"
  end
end
```

If you're working on development, make sure you clear your browser's cache.

There is [this method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Response.html#M000420), but didn't work for me. I don't know why, it may even be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I was able to get it to work is by setting the default charset

```
ActionController::Base.default_charset = nil
```

Also, setting the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header to `binary` will turn off the charset.

Answer (score 1):

Putting this in the controller did it for me:

```
ActionDispatch::Response::default_charset = nil
```

I put in in my base controller to remove it from all responses.

Comment: Honestly, this is what solved my issue. I just had to have an endpoint to do a validation which I'll remove later but none of the other solutions worked for me. Thanks!