# rails 2.3.5 setting content_type for the header and excluding charset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers

Rails 2.3.5 on Apache

I trying to deliver content to a extremely picky client application which I don't control.

The client expects to see this header: `Content-Type: text/xml`

When I try to return that with my dynamically rendered .erb I set the content type in the controller:

```
render :layout => false,  :content_type => 'text/xml'
```

I've also tried this based on my (obviously incorrect reading of the rails docs)

```
render :layout => false,  :content_type => 'text/xml', :charset => nil
```

But that renders this as the header: `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`

Unfortunately the client app (again not my fault) chokes on the ; charset=utf-8.

I tried the unaccepted answer on this SO question but it does not seem to work:

[Remove charset from Rails content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433059/remove-charset-from-rails-content-type)

Can anyone point me to the correct way to set this header without a charset?

Thank you

Comment: See the new answers on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433059/remove-charset-from-rails-content-type

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this solution](http://www.hokstad.com/rewriting-content-types-with-rack.html) would work for you? Hope it is exactly your problem.